# Function to calculate excel date in python

Tags: python

I have two dates in a csv file 9:20:00 AM and 4:09:21 PM and I need to read them in python. How do I find the time between these two dates?

Comment: Give a snippet of the CSV. Are the times in two lines or one line with comma etc...

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of reading CSV's in python. I would suggest you take a look at the official python [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)  library and [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and its easy to use [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function.

As for finding out the time difference, you will have to parse the strings and find the difference like this:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
a = "9:20:00 AM"
b = "4:09:21 PM"
a_obj = parse(a)
b_obj = parse(b)
time_diff = b_obj - a_obj
print time_diff.total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv` package of python to read and write csv files..

For example..

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in spamreader:
   #Your Logic
```

Using the package read the two dates. This may be string, and convert it into python date object and then find the time between two dates.

```
a = first_date
b = second_date
c = b - a
divmod(c.days * 86400 + c.seconds, 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be interested in `datetime` module.
Try this in your interpreter.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = datetime.strptime('9:20:00 AM','%I:%M:%S %p')
>>> a
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 20)
>>> b = datetime.strptime('4:09:21 PM','%I:%M:%S %p')
>>> b
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16, 9, 21)
>>> c= b-a
>>> c
datetime.timedelta(0, 24561)
```

So your *'9:20:00 AM'* was converted into a datetime object. Similarly the other time.

**NOTE:** **'%I:%M:%S %p'** This is the format in which you tell `strptime` to convert the string into a datetime object. After you perform operations on the datetime objects you get a `timedelta` object.

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 24561)
```

You can get the appropriate `days,seconds` from it. However you can't get `hours,minutes` for that you have to perform simple maths

Here is a code for you,

```
import datetime


def days_hours_minutes(td):
    return td.days, td.seconds//3600, (td.seconds//60)%60

a = datetime.datetime.strptime('9:20:00 AM','%I:%M:%S %p')
b = datetime.datetime.strptime('4:09:21 PM','%I:%M:%S %p')
c = datetime.timedelta(0, 24561)

days,hours,minutes = days_hours_minutes(c)
print("{0}:Days,{1}:Hours,{2}:Minutes".format(days,hours,minutes))
```

output:

```
0:Days,6:Hours,49:Minutes
```

I have defined a function `days_hours_minutes()` to print the days, hours,minutes.